# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error...

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Photo"

My insert code looks something like this...

```
if (image1.Source != null)
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream("@Photo", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Photo", imgByteArr));
}
else
{
   nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", DBNull.Value);
}
```

SQL Server: column name `Photo` and data type `image`

I tried the an example from [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-save-and-retrieve-images-in-c-wpf-application-from-sql-server-database/) website. I amended it a little bit because that website uses one click event handler where as I would like to use two click events handlers. One for browse button and the other for insert data. The following code is in the insert handle

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("@Photo", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", data);
```

The above code is giving me an error...

> Could not find file 'C:....\bin\Debug\@Photo'.

I think this giving me the error because I am not using open dialog coding the same method.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

**Update 1a**

This will take little time for me to grasp so I will go away. I will take advisement from the guys who have helped. Thanks

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s - I have seen comments on this website what you have mentioned. Advising to use varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead of image. So I will google if there is examples out there. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Instead of `image` - use `varbinary(max)` (not `varchar(max)` - that's for textual data)

Comment: I have changed the data type to varbinary(max) and amended the code to Habib and the error is same.

Comment: The `FileStream` constructor must reference **a valid file** in your filesystem - not a parameter in your SQL code! So instead of `new FileStream("@Photo", `, use `new FileStream("C:\\tmp\\myfile.jpg", ` or something. ...

Comment: @marc_s - I declared global string variable calling in the browse button and for FileStream. string Photo; FileStream fs = new FileStream(@Photo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", DBNull.Value);
```

change to

```
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Photo", DBNull.Value);
```

And also this

```
new FileStream("@Photo", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

is clearly wrong. What's @Photo? You can't directly bind SQL columns to C# code. You need to retrieve the value from the database, store it in some variable and then you can use it. Otherwise this code simply tries to find a file named @Photo, which results in an exception as you can see.

Comment: @Photo is Column name in SQL Server

Comment: @bucketblast, that's nice, but you can't bind columns to C# code like this. You need to retrieve the value and store it in some C# variable, that you can use later.. As you can see, it's trying to find some file called `@Photo`, which is nonsense for your purposes.

Comment: @Walter - I declared global string variable calling in the browse button and for FileStream. string Photo; FileStream fs = new FileStream(@Photo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  etc. So new FileStream("@Photo", I was massively wrong. So thanks Walther. I haven't got it completely working but this solved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `@` with parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Photo", imgByteArr));
                               ////^^^^ here
```