# Must declare the scalar variable or is it something else

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I asked this question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311731/must-declare-the-scalar-variable) and I am not sure if I am having the exact same problem, related problem or different problem but I will ask anyway.

I getting error of

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ID"

I have a global string variable...

```
string picLoc;
```

I have a insert method that looks something like this...

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into VolunteersMainDetails(ID , " + 
                  "Name, Photo)" +

                  "VALUES(@ID, " + 
                  "@Name, @Photo)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Photo", imgByteArr));
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
cmd.Parameters["@Photo"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

I am not sure if the clear parameter is the problem and if it is then if remove that code I will get error of...

> The variable name '@Photo' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

I believe I have used @Photo three times in the parameters if I don't use clear parameters.

If the clear parameter is not the problem then is the problem with code for photo? or Insert and Value code format?

The following method is to open dialog to find the image...

```
 private void brwsphoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileDialog fldlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fldlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures.ToString();
            fldlg.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
            fldlg.ShowDialog();
            {
              picLoc = fldlg.FileName;
              ImageSourceConverter isc = new ImageSourceConverter();
              image1.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty,isc.ConvertFromString(picLoc));
            }
            fldlg = null;
        }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
       }
    }
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me?

**Update 1a**

@Habib

I have amended the insert method as you have suggested as...

```
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("VPhoto", imgByteArr)); // removed this code
         cmd.Parameters.Clear(); // removed this code

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1); // this code included            
        cmd.Parameters["@Photo"].Value = DBNull.Value; // this code included
```

So now I am getting the following error

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

**Solution**

Solution is I change data type from varbinary(max) to image. This seems to solve the problem. I do not know how to use varbinary(max) for storing imaging and presently I am not bothered about it either.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is due to line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

You are clearing out parameters after adding them, you will get the same error for parameter `@Name`.

I am not really sure why you are adding `Photo` parameter in line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Photo", imgByteArr));
```

You can just comment out the lines:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Photo", imgByteArr));
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

and your code should be good enough

Comment: I have updated and I getting a new error. can you help me here as well? thanks in advance

Comment: @bucketblast, try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", DBNull.Value);`

Comment: Same error. I shouldn't imgByteArr referenced in the add parameter

Answer (score 0):

Solution is I change data type from varbinary(max) to image. This seems to solve the problem. I do not know how to use varbinary(max) for storing imaging.